# npm Use 2 Versions of Python

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, npm, python-2.x

Whenever I install certain `node` packages, there are errors involving the `Python` version. This is because I have both `Python 2.7` and `Python 3.3` (those were the latest versions last time I updated, but now there is `3.4`), but obviously I can only source one version in my `PATH` (any later folders are overridden). I have `Python 3.3` in my `PATH` because it's newer, but there are still so many programs, including `npm` modules, which use `Python 2`, over 5 years later.

Is there any way to include a "fallback" `Python` version, for modules which can not use version 3 yet? A general solution would be amazing, but I would at least like a solution for when installing `npm` modules. Keep in mind that some modules may be perfectly fine with `Python 3`, though I'm not sure if there are any which can not use `Python 2`. With that said, a solution which allows both, using the newest version when compatible and some older version when not, would be best.

For reference, my `Python 2.7` is installed in the `C:\Python27\python` folder and `Python 3.3` is in the `C:\Python33\python` folder. The `npm` error I am getting is:

> contextify@0.1.8 install c:\repos\konneka\node_modules\buster\node_modules\bus
>   ter-syntax\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
>   node-gyp rebuild

```
|
c:\repos\konneka\node_modules\buster\node_modules\buster-syntax\node_modules\jsd
om\node_modules\contextify>node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\no
de-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
when@1.3.0 node_modules\buster\node_modules\buster-server-cli\node_modules\buste
r-cli\node_modules\buster-configuration\node_modules\when
lodash@0.5.2 node_modules\buster\node_modules\buster-test-cli\node_modules\ramp\
node_modules\ramp-resources\node_modules\lodash
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.3.2, which is not support
ed by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & <
 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\np
m\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:108:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:97:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:645:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:
5)
ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
 command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\nod
e-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
esprima-fb@3001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb node_modules\browserify\node_modules\syntax-e
rror\node_modules\esprima-fb
http-proxy@0.10.4 node_modules\karma\node_modules\http-proxy
├── pkginfo@0.3.0
└── utile@0.2.1 (deep-equal@0.2.1, async@0.2.10, ncp@0.4.2, i@0.3.2, mkdirp@0.5.
0)
 cwd c:\repos\konneka\node_modules\buster\node_modules\buster-syntax\node_module
s\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: I was about to ask if I can install Node.js with Python 3.4, on Ubuntu. So that's a no, right?

Comment: I think I'm gonna ask it anyway, just to be sure.

Comment: @GuiImamura, it seems you don't understand the point of this question. First of all, all this is on Windows, not Ubuntu. Secondly, the Python version has nothing to do with whether you can install Node or not, though it matters when you're installing certain modules, which was the point of this question. If you can install Node with Python, that's awesome, but, again, not the point here.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the point here. I did ask my question and another user has explained it to me, thank you.

Comment: Can you link to your question, @GuiImamura? I'm curious now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209021/will-a-higher-version-of-python-build-node-js You can also find it on my profile, under "Questions"

Answer (score 2):

Use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [nodeenv](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv) and have any version combination you want.

Comment: What environment variable(s) should I use? How should I set this up? Where? In the `package.json`?

Comment: https://github.com/jhermann/hello-gulp-js#hello-gulp-js – you probably need CygWin for nodeenv to work on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

the way i flip between them is using the shebang at the beginning of python files

by including:

```
#!python2
```

at the beginning of the file, when you double click it the py.exe (or pyw.exe) passes it to that version of python (assuming it can find it) you can even pass it:

```
#!python2.7
```

to explicitly use version 2.7 assuming you have multiple version of python2 installed.

and to make use of this when installing modules, just edit the setup file to include that line as the first line, and then avoid putting python in the command line

assuming you use batch files to install modules like i do, where most people put:

```
python setup.py install
```

i then use:

```
setup.py install
```

this ensures that the setup script dictates which version of python it is installed to

i also found after a while of juggling python 2+3 that it made it easier for me to edit the registry so that when i right click a python file i could open it with idle 2 or 3.

EDIT:
i should mention that this only works properly when python3 was the last installed, as python 2 sets unfriendly values in the registry, and passes directly to the python2 version rather than checking the file first

Comment: What do you mean by the "setup file"? I'm using Windows, not Linux, as you may have been able to tell by the `PATH`/other parts of the question, so I don't use `Makefile`s (although perhaps I could). Also, what file do you put the shebangs in?

Comment: when you download a module it can come in two forms depending on where you get them from, some come as source code 
(which usually have a file called setup.py) which manages the install, and others are installed via executables, the executables manage themselves so you should only need to worry about installing modules from source

Comment: I am doing this all from `npm`, and the deps are often where the Python mismatch happens. If they don't have this shebang at the top, I don't want to put it there, as I may update or clone `npm` stuff many times and will probably forget.