# Will a higher version of Python build Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, python-3.4

I'm running the latest Ubuntu (14.04) and have just downloaded the Node.js tarball. I'm not very familiar with Python though, and although I love Ubuntu, I'm also not familiar with the process of downloading and installing stuff on Linux as well :/

It says on the [Node.js download page](http://nodejs.org/download/) that Python 2.6 or 2.7 is required, but I have found that newer versions of Python are available. Will a newer version of Python build it correctly?

Comment: using python >3.x for nodejs v8 you will receive the message "Please use either Python 2.6 or 2.7  " with configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not familiar with Linux then I don't think you want to compile node.js yourself from source. You can still use the binaries.tar.gz

There are Ubuntu packages that will install node.js for you! Installing from a package manager is easier, try https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

As for building from source, there are known issues with Python 3, ref https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation#known-issues, so maybe stick with 2.6 or 2.7

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: So, I downloaded the "Linux Binaries (.tar.gz)" from nodejs.org. It does all the installation for me?? @Qix This did answer my question actually, imho.

Comment: I didn't see that you edited the link. That instructions were exactly what I needed, now my Node.js and NPM are running perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Python versions starting with and including 2.6 up through before 3.0 should work fine. Python 3 brought some backwards incompatible changes with Python 2.x and AFAIK gyp has not been updated to support Python 3 yet.